# How to use Jawampa (Java WAMP implementation) to subcribe to an event

Tags: java, wamp, wamp-protocol

i want to use the poloniex API. https://poloniex.com/support/api/

So far i made Jawampa ( https://github.com/Matthias247/jawampa ) running with IntelliJ.

My first Question is, how to login successfuly? (The Docu of Jawampa doesnt help)

I got a API Key and a Secret. Which functions i have to use in the builder of Jawampa:

withRealm
withRoles
withConnectorProvider
withConnectionConfiguration
withSerializations
withStrictUriValidation
withAuthId
withAuthMethod
withObjectMapper

I have so far this code

```
     try {
        WampClientBuilder builder = new WampClientBuilder();
        builder.withConnectorProvider(connectorProvider)
                .withUri("wss://api.poloniex.com")
                .withAuthId("APIKEY")
                .withRealm("realm2")
                .withInfiniteReconnects()
                .withReconnectInterval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client1 = builder.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Is wss://api.poloniex.com correct or should i use wss://api.poloniex.com/returnTicker for that client?

Do I have to make always a new client for every URI?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. My first Question is, how to login successfuly?

You don't have to authenticate to access Poloniex Push API via WAMP protocol. Push API methods are public, so you don't have to supply the API key and secret. Just connect to wss://api.poloniex.com and subscribe to a desired feed (Ticker, Order Book and Trades, Trollbox).

Btw, you need to supply the API Key only with Trading API methods. And the Secret is used to sign a POST data.

2. Which functions i have to use in the builder of Jawampa:

This is how you connect to the Push API:

```
    WampClient client;
    try {
        WampClientBuilder builder = new WampClientBuilder();
        IWampConnectorProvider connectorProvider = new NettyWampClientConnectorProvider();
        builder.withConnectorProvider(connectorProvider)
                .withUri("wss://api.poloniex.com")
                .withRealm("realm1")
                .withInfiniteReconnects()
                .withReconnectInterval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client = builder.build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
```

Once your client is connected, you subscribe to a feed like this:

```
    client.statusChanged().subscribe(new Action1<WampClient.State>() {
        @Override
        public void call(WampClient.State t1) {
            if (t1 instanceof WampClient.ConnectedState) {
                subscription = client.makeSubscription("trollbox")
                        .subscribe((s) -> { System.out.println(s.arguments()); }
            }
        }
    });
    client.open();
```

3. Is wss://api.poloniex.com correct or should i use 
   wss://api.poloniex.com/returnTicker for that client?

wss://api.poloniex.com is correct. Besides, returnTicker belongs to the Public API and is accessed via HTTP GET requests.

4. Do I have to make always a new client for every URI?

In respect to the Push API, once you connected a client to wss://api.poloniex.com, you can use this client to make subscriptions to multiple feeds. For example:

```
client.statusChanged().subscribe(new Action1<WampClient.State>() {
        @Override
        public void call(WampClient.State t1) {
            if (t1 instanceof WampClient.ConnectedState) {
                client.makeSubscription("trollbox")
                        .subscribe((s) -> { System.out.println(s.arguments()); });
                client.makeSubscription("ticker")
                        .subscribe((s) -> { System.out.println(s.arguments()); });
            }
        }
    });
```

However, according to Jawampa Docs:

> After a WampClient was closed it can not be reopened again. Instead of this a new instance of the WampClient should be created if necessary.